# Flutter - Floating hint inside the OutlineInputBorder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve the `TextFormField` just like the image attached.
[image]

This is my code currently:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
      controller: widget.controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: _color,
        prefixIcon: _buildPrefixIcon(),
        labelText: widget.hintText,
        hintStyle: context.textStyle.subHeadline.copyWith(color: widget.hintColor ?? context.colors.textSecondaryOnLightBackground),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 8),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.fieldsColor),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.fieldsColor),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.fieldsColor),
        ),
      ),
      style: context.textStyle.subHeadline.copyWith(color: widget.textColor ?? context.colors.textPrimaryOnLightBackground),
      textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
      keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
      obscureText: widget.obscureText ?? false,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
    );
  }
```

Is there a way to create a floating hint inside the outline border?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the border from the `TextField` itself, and wrap it with a `Container` that you will use to theme your text field.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyTextField({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 72.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0, vertical: 8.0),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: const TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // remove; managed by Container.
          border: InputBorder.none, // as above
          labelText: "Mobile number",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @offworldwelcome ! That's what I think too. Looks like Material.dart doesn't support this kind of design

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to find a workaround. I just wrap the `TextFormField` with `Container`, set the `TextFormField` border as `UnderlineInputBorder`, and make the border side transparent or the background color of the screen so that the underline border will disappear.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: _borderColor),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
        controller: widget.controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: _fillColor,
          prefixIcon: _buildPrefixIcon(),
          labelText: widget.hintText,
          labelStyle: context.textStyle.subHeadline.copyWith(color: _borderColor),
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 8),
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.backgroundLightColor),
          ),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.backgroundLightColor),
          ),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.backgroundLightColor),
          ),
        ),
        style: context.textStyle.subHeadline.copyWith(color: widget.textColor ?? context.colors.textPrimaryOnLightBackground),
        textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
        keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
        obscureText: widget.obscureText ?? false,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Let me know if there's any solution that can also worked.